# Passing in unlimited tuples as arguments at end of method

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a function that can take in any number of tuples at the end.

This would be very useful when writing several dataframes to the same Excel file, such as one report with several subjects and their respective sheet specifications (Science, 1, 1) (Math, 2, 1) (English, 3, 1).

For this example I have `def visualize(project_dir, report_name, df, sheet_name, header_row):`

but I want to make it like `def visualize(project_dir, report_name, *(df, sheet_name, header_row)):`

```py
def visualize(project_dir, report_name, df, sheet_name, header_row):
    def template_path(project_path, report_name):
        return project_path + "\\" + report_name + " Template.xlsx"

    def timestamp():
        return datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %I%M%p")

    def output_path(project_path, report_name):
        return project_path + "\\" + report_name + " Report " + timestamp() + ".xlsx"

    template_path = template_path(project_dir, report_name)
    output_path = output_path(project_dir, report_name)

    try:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(output_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=header_row, index=False,
                                           header=False)
        writer.save()

        paste_formatting(template_path, output_path, sheet_name)
    except:
        print("Formatting failed; reverting to raw data")
        with pd.ExcelWriter(output_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
        writer.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `*(df, sheet_name, header_row)`. Just use `*args` and then loop over them.

```
def visualize(project_dir, report_name, *args):
    ...
    for df, sheet_name, header_row in args:
        ...
```

You would then call it like:

```
visualize("dirname", "report_name", (df1, "sheet1", ["col1", "col2"]), (df2, "sheet2", ["heading1", "heading2", "heading3"]), ...)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to put a useful link as a resource here too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfI4cR66jQY

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `**kwargs` or `*args` for that respect. It allows you to pass in variable arguments to the function, and once the function is called, `kwargs` becomes a dictionary of the extra variables defined and `args` becomes a list. More info about it here: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/